# Access to private file only from website, not using direct link

Tags: files

My private files has a visible URL like the following: https://mywebsite.com/system/files/myimage.jpg.

How can I restrict access to the file, so it cannot be viewed directly from this URL but only from link on my website?

I have tried to use SESSION as follows.

```
$_SESSION['file-access'] = TRUE;
$output = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'foto_preview', 'path' => $uri));
```

Then I controlled in `hook_file_download()` if the SESSION key 'file-access' exists, but the session key never exists.
The image I wish to display is the value of an image field. I cannot use `$user` because I wish to display private files also for anonymous users.

Can anybody help on how to restrict the direct access to a private file, but allow access from website?

EDIT 30.7.2013: my mistake, using sessios works OK, I had a mistake in another unrelated part of code. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [private filesystem as shown in documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file). Then you can create custom module to implement more advanced rules, like link timeouts et cetera.

Comment: I am using private filesystem. The problem is, how apply this system specifically for my situation. I have set my image field as private files and I am using hook_file_download. But how should I solve my problem? Link timeouts doesn't solve exactly the problem, there is still chance to use the timeout for unallowed visit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this similar with hot linking htaccess protection.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.tld/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/image_or_page_to_show_instead [R,L]
```

Just put your condition instead `\.(gif|jpg)$`

Comment: +1, but it has to be pointed out that referer comes from the client and this protection is easily circumvented.

Comment: I can't understand what you are really trying to do.
User can download file if only he visited any site page before?

I can emulate this with curl, save session && cookies and then download file.

So, what kind of profit you are wanna to reach. :)

Comment: I tried to use session (as it is code snippet in question) but for an unknowned reason, I cannot get the session value in hook_file_download. The best solution for me to use the $_SESSION, if it works somehow.

Comment: As pointed by Letharion, I am afraid, that skilled programmers can circumvent the restriction

Comment: The sessions works in hook_file_download, I have mistake in other place in code. The solution is in code snippet in question.